# pthread_cond_wait and syslog writer conflict

Tags: linux, gcc, pthreads, threadpool, rsyslog

I am currently developing a pthread-related socket communication program with gcc / g++. I'm having a problem using syslog.

If I do not use the `syslog()` function, `pthread_cond_wait` works correctly when I send `pthread_cond_signal`.

However, when using the `syslog()` function, if I send `pthread_cond_signal`, then `pthread_cond_wait` has no response.

Is this a problem with syslog?

Comment: There is no problem, in general, with using `syslog()` and `pthread_cond_wait()` together.  You are probably missing a predicate with your use of `pthread_cond_wait()`, but you should update your question with an example of the code that is not functioning as you want.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).